# Blender is rendering white in Cycles Reder

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm actually using Blender 2.79 on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and I tried rendering in Cycles Render my scene but it renders a complete white image, however, in Blender Render, it gives me my scene with no problem.

[image: Cycles Render]
So this is my final render in Cycles...

[image: Blender Render]
...and this is my render in Blender Render.

So I would like to know what is causing that and how to fix it.

Comment: It’s hard to tell without your blend file, but I’m wondering if this has something to do with your lighting being turned up too high. Check the World emission strength. It should not be more than about three if more than one. The same goes for any sun lamps. What kind of lighting do you have in the scene?

Comment: ZargulTheWizard, thanks for you help, it was my point light that was too powerful and too close of my objects and the camera.